# Going to Marketplace in Trial Mode with an XNA Game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I want to detect if my game is in trail mode and make the user go to the marketplace to purchase it.

I did the code that was [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282459.aspx)

The code samlpe they provided doesn't work though

```
if (Guide.IsTrialMode)
{
    Guide.ShowMarketplace(signedInGamer.PlayerIndex);
}
```

it gives `The name SignedInGamer doesn't exist in the current context`

I tried to play with it a little  bit and modified it to be:

```
if (Guide.IsTrialMode)
{
   //Guide.ShowMarketplace(signedInGamer.PlayerIndex);
    Guide.ShowMarketplace(PlayerIndex.One);                
}
```

it works now but on the emulator it goes to the marketplace and gives:

[image]

I am not sure that's because the game is in debug mode and hasn't been published yet, or that's because of the modification I made?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because it hasn't been published in the Marketplace. The page you linked to has this note:

> When the method Guide.ShowMarketplace is called on an application that
>   has not yet been published to the Windows Phone Marketplace, it will
>   result in an error being displayed. **If this error has the error code
>   805a0194, then the call was successful and will operate correctly when
>   the application is published.** When your application is published, the
>   Guide.ShowMarketplace will automatically detect your application’s
>   unique ID and launch the correct details page in the Windows Phone
>   Marketplace client application.